# how to load a mysql query result using express and socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I am studying node and express. I have a table of inventory item and I want to view this on my web browser that's why I used socket.io with express.

But when there's a connection I can't load the data. Here's my code:

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'node'    
});

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/bower_components', express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

connection.connect();

/**example from express

connection.connect();
connection.query('SELECT * FROM inventory', function(err, rows, fields){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(rows);
});
connection.end();

**/

function loadList() {

    connection.query('SELECT * FROM inventory', function(err, rows, fields){
        if(err) throw err;
        return rows;
    });

}

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user is connected!!');

    socket.on('inventory list', function(data){

        return 'hello world'; // i pass a simple return to test if this can return something

        /*
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM inventory', function(err, rows, fields){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(rows);
        });
        */

    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected!');
    });

});

http.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on ' + port);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Invertory Sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>sample</p>
        <p class="test"></p>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            try {
                var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8000');
                //console.log(socket);
            }catch(e) {
                console.log('ERROR OCURRED: ' + e);
            }

            if(socket !== undefined) {
                socket.on('inventory list', function(data) { console.log(data); //i console but no response. });
            }

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can you help me? I am extremely new in nodejs but I have some basic understanding. Or can you provide me a good example for this?

Thats all thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both, client and server, your are listening an event('inventory list'), but no one emits this event.

If you want to send the list to the client on conection you can try something like this on server:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){

    console.log('A user is connected!!');

    socket.emit('inventory list', { list: 'mylist' });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected!');
    });
});
```

http://socket.io/docs/server-api/